# с сохранёнными cookies вновь требуется авторизация

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

я хочу обойти капчу используя куки, куки сохраняются если нажать Ctrl + Q. Я ввел почту и пароль, прошел капчу и сохранил куки. Но когда я заново открываю сайт и загружаю куки то приходится опять писать пароль и проходить капчу

вот код:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pickle

from time import sleep

import keyboard



options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_argument("start-maximized")

# чтобы не определялось как тестовое ПО
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


def save_cookie():
    with open("cookie.pkl", 'wb') as filehandler:
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)
        print('saved')

def load_cookie():
    with open("cookie.pkl", 'rb') as cookiesfile:
        cookies = list(pickle.load(cookiesfile))
        for cookie in cookies:
            print(cookie)
            driver.add_cookie(dict(cookie))


# где-то прочитал что так нужно делать чтобы сайт не понял что это бот
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    'source': '''
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_JSON;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Object;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Proxy;
  '''
}) 


driver.get('https://2captcha.com/enterpage')
# load_cookie() # перед вторым запуском надо раскоментировать
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + Q', save_cookie)

sleep(100)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Создайте папку профиля. Пройти авторизацию. При повторном заходе авторизация не требутся, т.к. куки сохранились в папке профиля

Comment: Сергей Ш, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я создал в хроме профиль в котором ввел имейл и пароль на сайте и загрузил его в коде, теперь всё работает. Для этого надо добавить такие опции:

```py
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={путь_к_папке_с_профилями}")
options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={папка_профиля}")
```

путь к профилю можно посмотреть если в хроме написать `chrome://version/`