# Как получить доступ к активной сессии гугл хрома через selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите как получить доступ к активной сессии гугл хрома через selenium? Написал программу, которая заходит на сайт и считывает нужную инфу с сайта через selenium, но всё это происходит через отдельное открывающееся окно гугл хрома и каждый раз открывает новое чистое окно гугл хрома и в нём нужный сайт заново, с нуля. В принципе всё работает как нужно, но сейчас появилась потребность в том, чтобы считывались данные с заранее открытой вкладки с сайтом в обычном режиме (чтобы не открывалось отдельное окно гугл хрома и в нём открывался нужный сайт, а чтобы данные считывались уже с открытого браузера). Код ниже открывает новое окно гугл хрома, а в нём нужный сайт. То, что мне нужно описал выше.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://нужный сайт')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549776/%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-cookies-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment2790366_1549776